# Python exception - need finally, don't need except

Tags: python, exception, try-catch-finally, try-finally

I have some code which represents a test case within a proprietary testing framework that looks something like this:

```
def test_alarm(self):
    self.setup_some_test_data()
    try:
        self.send_alarm_message()
    except:
        print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()
    finally:
        self.teardown_some_test_data()
```

I've been told to drop the print as it's not necessary and the test framework will in any case catch any exceptions, which is preferred to catching them here, but I still need to always clear the data down, as in the `finally` block.

Do I just drop the `except` block entirely? Alternatively, how, can I structure the code to effectively have an empty `except` block and retain the `finally`? Is this good practice in Python or is there a better way to do it?

*Edit* Note that I did try just dropping the `except` block entirely, and I had no obvious run-time problems, though since exceptions are unlikely in the the call to `send_alarm_message()`, it was unclear to me how it would work if an exception was thrown or whether this was considered good practice by the Python community.

Comment: *"Do I just drop the `except` block entirely?"* - why didn't you try it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I did try it, and I had no obvious run-time problems, though since exceptions are unlikely, it was unclear to me how it would work if an exception was thrown or whether this was considered good practice by the Python community.

Comment: Note that some of the examples [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) don't include `except`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can drop the except block completely, it is a valid python syntax to have just `try` and `finally` . Example -

```
In [58]: try:
   ....:     print("Blah")
   ....: finally:
   ....:     print("halB")
   ....:
Blah
halB
```

Please note this will not catch any Exceptions/Errors that occur within the `try` block, and I am guessing that is what you want.

I have seen this used at quite some places, where we are creating some variables/resources that need to be cleared irrespective of whether any exceptions/errors occur, but we do not want to handle any Exceptions at that particular place.

Answer (score 2):

Either drop the except Block, or improove it really by adding

```
except [Exception-Class]:
    pass
```

where [Exception-Class] is the exception to be excepted. This adds some sugar on it, because really unexpected Errors are not getting catched by this. (Or add this as a seperate:

```
except Exception, ex:
    print "Unexpected error:", ex
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do anything in `except` block, then you can `pass` it.

```
try:
    self.send_alarm_message()
except:
    pass
finally:
    self.teardown_some_test_data()
```